# Which GPUs does CodeXL support?

Tags: gpu, system-requirements, codexl

Now that CodeXL is open-source and openly developed, I'd expect it to support more than just AMD GPUs. Is this true?

**Which GPUs does CodeXL support?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is buried deep in the GPUOpen site, in the [Release Notes for the latest version - 2.2](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL/releases/download/v2.2/CodeXL_Release_Notes.pdf), the System Requirements section.

The document is lengthy and copyrighted so I won't reproduce the information from it here, except the piece that I was most interested in:

> For **GPU API-Level Debugging**, a working OpenCL/OpenGL configuration is required (AMD or other)

So non-AMD GPUs are supported.